# Real-time database

Tags: java, android, firebase-database

Работаю над проектом, на данный момент все реализовано на `sqlLite`

Сейчас нужно реализовывать регистрацию пользователя + сохранение всех данных в облаке,  чтоб был доступ с разных устройств

Гуглил про `Real-time database` очень много информации про `Firebase` там есть как раз авторизация и бд

**Вопрос 1.** как правильно реализовать синхронизацию с использованием `Firebase`?

**2.** Какие еще есть `Real-time database` и есть смысл использовать что-то другое когда есть `Firebase`?

Comment: Есть ещё Realm. В т.ч. у них вроде появилось решение для сервера а-ля Firebase.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я просто пока не совсем понимаю с чего начинать, чтоб синхронизация была, как я понял это noSql бд и как связать авторизацию пользователя и именно его данные не знаю, в интернете кучу примеров, но там отдельно как прикрутить бд firebase но тогда она будет для всех одна, это мне не подходит, как быть, есть идеи?

Comment: Всё просто - храните данные юзера в ячейке с его ID. Так только этот юзер будет иметь доступ к этим данным.

Comment: Ну теоретически понимаю что так нужно делать, а как это реализовать в жизни? Я добавил авторизацию Firebase пользователь может регистрироваться в консоли Firebase появляется новый пользователь, но что делать дальше не понимаю, у примеру в sql у меня были связи между таблицами, а как это реализовать в Firebase, и сразу вопрос если пользователь не хочет включать синхронизацию, то что прога не работает никак?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, можете подсказать?

Comment: Сложно в рамках коммента/ответа рассказать как NoSQL использовать... В кратце код будет выглядеть так: `databaseRef.child(userID).setValue(dataModel);` для записи и `databaseRef.child(userID).addSingleValueEventListener(...);` для единичного получения данных, ранее туда записанных. Для постоянного получения всех изменений - `addValueEventListener`. Просто попробуйте по доке простые примеры.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо прочитаю, ещё один вопрос, при запуске приложениия есть дефолтные данные которые обязательно требуются для запуска, если пользователь хочет использовать приложениия без регистрации только локально, как быть в этом случае?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне кажется я нашёл, то что искал, нет? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000899/how-to-link-between-authenticated-users-and-database-in-firebase

Comment: В зависимости от от типа, сложности и объёма данных можно выбрать SharedPreferences или БД. Если собираетесь юзать Firebase, то можно попробовать локальные данные хранить в Realm - это тоже NoSQL БД на схожих принципах.

Comment: Да, я как раз это и писал парой комментов выше.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а если локальные данные будут в другой бд и через какое-то время пользователь захочет включить синхронизацию, как быть в этом случае, ведь 2 бд не будут конфликтовать или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: опечатка, хотел написать будут конфликтовать?

Comment: Все данные храните и отображайте из локальной БД и обновляйте их из удалённой. Конфликты возникнуть могут только если вы сами их допустите. Сами по себе обе БД никак взаимодействовать без вашего участия не будут. Разруливать конфликты придётся вручную. Тут всё от реализации будет зависеть. Общепринятые подходы если и есть то мне они не известны. Разве что отдавать предпочтение при конфликте данным из удалённой БД

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, понял вас, спасибо, буду читать про noSql